# What is the best data strcture to choose and implementation to build for this kind data in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures

```
                    StorageRoom
                     /       \
                    /         \
                   /           \
                  "A"          "B"
                  / \          / \
                 /   \        /   \
               "0"   "1"     "0"  "1"  (node at this level has 3 children)
              / | \
             /  |  \             ====
                                each node at this level has four children
          "0"  "1"  "2"          ====
          /|\ \
         / | \  \              

     "0" "1" "2" "3"           
      |   |   |    |
   Obj1 Obj2 Obj3 Obj4
```

bottom level has different type as(not string),

Also , considering the can be diverge to wider and more children in future, and nodes and each level might be different.

Currently; I'm thinking nested hashMap, tree. but I couldn't think a way to recursively build such a data structure.
To build the map; we will be given the name(String) and numbers(int) for each level. Like {"AB", "01", "012","0123", Object} so that we can build such structure

Also; I need to have an implementation such that returns the path(from root to object) when the object is given

Meanwhile; given a path; quickly return the object. My current thoughts:

```
public class StorageRoom<T> {

   String name; //name for the node
   LinkedList<StorageRoom<T>> children;
   LinkedList<Product> product; // represents the bottom level where children is a product

   public StorageRoom(String name, LinkedList children) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = children
  } 


   public StorageRoom(String name, LinkedList product) { //represents the bottom level child
    this.name = name;
    this.product = product
  } 

}
```

But I don't know how to build such structure recursively.

Comment: A linked list that has an array of children instead of a child may be a good place to start. What you think.

Comment: Your usage example is unclear. Write actual code that illustrates how the structure would be initialized and used. Then we can give you better idea how to define its internals.

Comment: Thats just a tree with fixed number of nodes for each level. Shouldn't be too hard to implement that. The rest is just plain old recursion. You should narrow down the actual problem if you expect a helpful answer. I.e. what is the tree used for/why exactly that structure?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can build a node structure like the one below:

```
class Node<T> {
    T value;
    List<Node<?>> children;
}
```

Then you can use a Tree structure like the one below:

```
class Tree {
    Node<String> root;

    Node<?> findNode(String path);
    void addNode(Node<?> newNode);
    void validate(Node<?> node, int level);
    // All other tree operations go here

}
```

The most important methods you need to add will be to search for a node based on path, then to validate and add new nodes to your tree. All these will go into the `Tree` data structure.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why the down vote? The initial question was to suggest a data structure which is what I did. If the question is later edited to ask a different thing,  does that make my answer unworthy?

Comment: thanks for the reply; right now is that; I'm have troubling to build such a tree; the only way I can think of is using nested loop (possible four); and I couldn't think of recursive way; any hint could be helpful

Comment: There are two ways to build your tree. One takes input from a user or another using existing data in a file or some data base. For just creating the nodes you may not need recursion. The recursion will come into place inside the `find` method.